# xlwings module installation issue

Tags: python, pip, xlwings

I tried the command:

```
python3 -m pip install xlwings
```

But I got the following (long) error. The error is too long so i put only the end. Installation of other packages with the same command are working.  Do somebody know how to solve that please?

```
...


      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=567 -DPSUTIL_OSX=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c psutil/_psutil_common.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_common.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=567 -DPSUTIL_OSX=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c psutil/_psutil_posix.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_posix.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=567 -DPSUTIL_OSX=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c psutil/_psutil_osx.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_osx.o
  In file included from psutil/_psutil_osx.c:36:
  In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:43:
  In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:72:
  /usr/local/include/Block.h:16:3: error: Never include this file directly. Use <lzma.h> instead.
  #       error Never include this file directly. Use <lzma.h> instead.
          ^
  /usr/local/include/Block.h:93:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_check'
          lzma_check check;
          ^
 ...
          lzma_bool reserved_bool2;
          ^
  /usr/local/include/Block.h:264:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_bool'
          lzma_bool reserved_bool3;
          ^
  fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
  20 errors generated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psutil
  Running setup.py clean for psutil
Failed to build psutil
Installing collected packages: psutil, xlwings
    Running setup.py install for psutil ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/cy/jtv0bpc11vsbbmfhjzz5zlz00000gr/T/pip-install-3i68cw09/psutil/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/cy/jtv0bpc11vsbbmfhjzz5zlz00000gr/T/pip-install-3i68cw09/psutil/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/cy/jtv0bpc11vsbbmfhjzz5zlz00000gr/T/pip-record-k62qhrl9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /private/var/folders/cy/jtv0bpc11vsbbmfhjzz5zlz00000gr/T/pip-install-3i68cw09/psutil/
    Complete output (106 lines):
  ...
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psutil/arch
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psutil/arch/osx
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=567 -DPSUTIL_OSX=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c psutil/_psutil_common.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_common.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=567 -DPSUTIL_OSX=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c psutil/_psutil_posix.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_posix.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=567 -DPSUTIL_OSX=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c psutil/_psutil_osx.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_osx.o
    In file included from psutil/_psutil_osx.c:36:
    In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:43:
    In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:72:
    /usr/local/include/Block.h:16:3: error: Never include this file directly. Use <lzma.h> instead.
    #       error Never include this file directly. Use <lzma.h> instead.
            ^
    /usr/local/include/Block.h:93:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_check'
            lzma_check check;
   ...
            lzma_bool ignore_check;
            ^
    /usr/local/include/Block.h:263:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_bool'
            lzma_bool reserved_bool2;
            ^
    /usr/local/include/Block.h:264:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_bool'
            lzma_bool reserved_bool3;
            ^
    fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
    20 errors generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/cy/jtv0bpc11vsbbmfhjzz5zlz00000gr/T/pip-install-3i68cw09/psutil/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/cy/jtv0bpc11vsbbmfhjzz5zlz00000gr/T/pip-install-3i68cw09/psutil/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/cy/jtv0bpc11vsbbmfhjzz5zlz00000gr/T/pip-record-k62qhrl9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

EDIT: I have added part of the error as it could be useful.

I had to cut the error as it is not accepted because too long.

Comment: Please add more of the error. If possible, include the full error message

Comment: Which Python version are you using, 3.8?

Comment: @FelixZumstein The last line shows 3.7.

Comment: The issue happens when installing `psutil`, a dependency of xlwings. It's a Mojave issue and can be fixed like described here: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3438#issuecomment-435169249 `sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /`

Comment: @Felix Zumstein I installed successfully by running the command. But I still have this issue. I've added more about the error

Comment: maybe this helps: https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/1551

Comment: @Felix Zumstein Thanks man, I was looking for that for 2 days...